# PGAdmin: Using Sequence to set the column ID by default isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sequence, pgadmin

In PGAdmin, I created a table with few columns. The ID column is supposed to be 'NOT NULL' with a sequence -->

```
nextval('my_table_id_seq'::regclass)
```

In the sequence configuration I have added in Definiation-->

```
Increment 1
Current Value 1
Minimum 1
Maximum 9999
Cache 1
```

In my Rails DB, when I try to

```
p = MyTable.new
p.col1 = 'some_val'
p.col2 = 'other_val'
p.save
```

I get an error --> ID is NULL.
I expected the ID to be picked up by default and incremented by 1 for each new entry.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. I had not marked ID as a primary key. Once I did that, it started working fine